# problem importing CPX library to use Device Simulator or Visual Sudio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, simulator

I'm following our tutorial. I already had python set up in VSC but I'm trying to use the Device Simulator express now. I'm getting an error when I hit play. It seems the system can't find the library error on line:

from adafruit_circuitplayground import cp

The error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/YayaLenovoFlex/Documents/Python Scripts/trySimulator1.py", line 12, in 
from adafruit_circuitplayground import cp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adafruit_circuitplayground'

Please help.  I've very new to Visual Studio Code.  I would rather use VSC then the MU editor if I can.

Thanks

Comment: Confirm that the extension ‘Device Simulator Express’ is successfully installed from the VSCode extension store, and then follow the steps in this link(the'how to use' part.). This line of code is automatically generated.link:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.devicesimulatorexpress

Comment: How about the issue, is there anything to update?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed libraries by this command?

```
pip install adafruit_circuitplayground
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.   I tried to install the library in a Windows CMD window. Is this correct? I got an error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement adafruit_circuitplayground (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for adafruit_circuitplayground    What did I do wrong